# Merging multiple GeoJSON files into one file with layers

Tags: qgis, geojson

What is the best way to merge several GeoJSON files of different types into a single GeoJSON but where each original GeoJSON is its own data layer within the final output?

Been playing with QGIS and can't figure out a way to get this result without combining all the data together into one layer (which when I have polygons and points I can not do).

Can most likely write a script to read in and convert all the JSONs and then write out to a single file, but just wondering if there is a better/built in way of doing this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You need to use a better format for that - try a geopackage

Comment: There is no such thing as *layers* in the GeoJSON specification; to stay in the realm of valid GeoJSON structure you can either 1) group homogeneous geometry types into their *Multi* types (by any category you want), or 2) use a *GeometryCollection* and simply add all your *Feature*s to it. I would assume 1) is the recommended way. *FeatureCollection*s of *FeatureCollection*s, while possible, are not considered geometry objects (but *foreign objects*), and software supporting the specs are not required to support reading them.

Comment: How the specification puts it `GeoJSON Text A GeoJSON text is a JSON text and consists of a single GeoJSON object.` You seem to be after many FeatureCollection objects.